# How to find mean value of a random process from power spectral density?

Tags: power-spectral-density

I have a  periodic function that is given as x(t). I found out the power spectral density. How do I find out the mean value from the power spectral density. I know how to find out the mean square value. And also I found out the mean by directly using the given function.But my Professor insists on finding the mean the other way. I have searched the internet but could not find anything useful. I have attached the  problem statement. Thank you in advance.[image: Question number 14]

Comment: it’s not random, at least the way its shown. it is a saw tooth. not random at all

Comment: I agree with Stans comment: this is _not_ a random process at all.  Find the Fourier _series_ $\sum_n c_n \exp\left(-j2\pi n \frac tT\right)$ of $x(t)$. Then the Fourier _transform_ is $X(f) = \sum_n c_n \delta\left(f-\frac nT\right)$ and the PSD is $\sum_n |c_n|^2  \delta\left(f-\frac nT\right)$. Can you now figure out the mean from the PSD?

Comment: @DilipSarwate Thanks for that method it really is helpful. I calculated PSD by finding the autocorrelation and transforming it. However my question was to find the mean from the PSD and it was not obvious for me and hence I was asking this question. Thanks for your time. P.S I still could not find the mean from PSD

Comment: Further hint:  The mean of a deterministic signal $x(t)$ is defined as $$\bar{x} = \lim_{T\to\infty} \frac 1T \int_{-T}^T x(t) \,\mathrm dt$$ which is zero for finite-energy signals with conventional Fourier transforms (meaning no impulses). _Periodic_ signals such as the one you have don't have Fourier transforms in the conventional sense; they have Fourier _series_ which are accommodated into Fourier transform via impulses.  If the PSD is known to be $\sum_{-\infty}^\infty |c_n|^2\delta\left(f - \frac nT\right)$, can you figure out the value of $c_0$?

Comment: Thanks. That definitely brought some insight into my understanding.

Answer (score -1):

You must have calculated the PSD using a Fourier Transform right? If that is the case, you probably know that X(0) or the DC component that one obtains from the Fourier Transform is simply the sum of the signal components (assuming that you sample the signal and then take a DFT).

So now that you've obtained the sum of the signal from the PSD, you can obviously find the mean

Comment: There is no need to take samples and compute the DFT. This is a periodic signal for which the Fourier _series_ is easy to compute (it might even be found as an example in some textbooks) and so the Fourier _transform_ is an impulse train spaced apart by the fundamental frequency of the sawtooth function.

Comment: I didn't say there was a need to sample the signal. I was merely suggesting a way to do it for a general signal on a computer